# Android Intent passing parcelable object vs passing Json string

Tags: android, json, serialization, jackson, parcelable

I am aware that there are some answers to my question, but the answers are not very elaborate or convincing.
In my program, in order to transmit data from one activity to another, I'm converting the contents of the POJO class into a Json String and passing via bundle (Method1).

**METHOD1**

```
String jsonString = JacksonSingleton.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
bundle.putExtra(KEY_STR, jsonString)
```

In Method 2, I am passing a `Parcelable` object in the bundle.

**METHOD2**

```
bundle.putExtra(KEY_STR, parcelableObject);
```

If I were to implement Method 2, I'll have to implement `Parcelable` interface and write custom code for marshaling and unmarshaling my POJO class fields.

My question, which of these methods is better/recommended in terms of **performance**? Method 1 is very convenient but I want to follow best practices.

Comment: Guys, please don't downvote the question without even commenting or answering about it....

Comment: I am not trying to compare between serializable and parcelable. I am just trying to check performance difference between passing a normal string and a parcelable object.

Comment: if it was faster just to use any string based serialization i think that android guys didnt even bother with introducing `Parcelable` stuff

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**EDIT:**
If you hate writing 'Parcelable' boilerplate code like me, you could use the [Parcelable code generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator) plugin with your Android Studio/IntelliJ IDE. It will auto generate the methods for marshalling and unmarshalling your class fields. Very easy to use and highly recommended.

---

As much as I hate answering my own questions, I thought of sharing my observations that could help other developers in future.

Transmission of data from one activity to another can be done using either passing Serializable or Parcelable Objects in an activity intent. Android developer website recommends using [Parcelable interface for this purpose](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).

However, my question was pertaining to the **efficiency comparison** between passing Parcelable object and JSON string.

To test this, I used an old and low-end Android device. I launched an activity by sending a large Parcelable Object in an activity intent. Next, I launched the same activity using the JSON String of the same object in the activity intent. What I observed was a significant observable latency while launching an activity by sending a JSON String instead of Parcelable Object.

In conclusion, even if we pass a JSON String, [Java String object always implements Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Google recommends using Parcelable instead of Serializable objects. This will usually be insignificant in case of strings of negligible length. However, in the case of massive Json Strings of massive objects, The efficiency will certainly take a toll.

You could refer this for [performance benchmark of Parcelable vs Serializable](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development).

---

**TLDR:**

- `Parcelable` - More boilerplate code, better performance and a better engineering practice overall.
- `Serializable` - Less code, easy to learn and acceptable if you're not obsessed with performance/best practices.

Comment: Have you tried passing a JSON string in a Parcelable ? You might get the best of the both worlds in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object/array is global usage, and can transfer over internet, we can handle it in the same way by different programming language on different platforms, and is easily stored. If the machine is not so slow and the data is not so huge, I prefer use JSON.

What for put extra with a large data to send to another activity? Sometimes I just send an ID for stored data or use a singleton to handle object... (Can another app access the Parcelable object?)

So the Parcelable is for cross process used in the same app.. Just like RemoteView and Service use it to transfer data for convenient...